# Show that the set of powers of ten is countably infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, relations, cardinals, infinite-groups

My question asks: An $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is called a power of ten if there exists a $y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $10^y = x$. Show that the set of powers of ten is countably infinite.

I understand that for the set of powers to be countably infinite, there must exist a bijection between the set and $\mathbb{N}$.

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to properly prove this! Please help!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 5):

$y\mapsto 10^y$ is your desired bijection: It is onto by definition, and readily verified to be one-to-one.

Comment: Hagen, could you explain this a little more? How would you go about showing the bijection. Obviously you need to show the injection and surjection, but how...specific to this example? I know this would be simple for you, but I can't quite get there. None of our course literature covers questions like this. @badatmaths have you had any success developing your solution any further?